# Trying to connect my webservice to RestAngular live demo on plunkr

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services, restangular

I am deep down in another one of those angularJS learning valleys. I'm trying to get the RestAngular live demo on plunker working in our C# .net environment. When I get to this line:

```
$scope.projects = Restangular.all("projects").getList().$object;
```

I get this back in the response body.

```
[ { "_id" : { "id" : 13} , "name" : "choiceBro" , "description" : "devils" , "site" : "https://www.google.co.uk/" , "id" : "923856329485632"} , 
  { "_id" : { "id" : 14} , "name" : "TESTING2" , "description" : "435q1gfdgfdgsda" , "site" : "http://www.567567.try"} ,
  { "_id" : { "id" : 15} , "name" : "Updated" , "description" : "435q1gfdgfdgsda" , "site" : "http://www.567567.try"} ,...
```

When I hit my webservice:

```
$scope.projects = Restangular.all("projects").getList().$object;
```

I get this back in the response body:

```
[{"id":1,"description":"All information everywhere","name":"Google","site":"http://Google.com","CreateId":"CRGA","CreateTimestamp":"\/Date(1445003454083)\/","ModifyId":"*Load*","ModifyTimestamp":"\/Date(1445003454083)\/"} ,
  {"id":2,"description":"All things Microsoft","name":"Microsoft","site":"http://Microsoft.com","CreateId":"CRGA","CreateTimestamp":"\/Date(1445003454083)\/","ModifyId":"*Load*","ModifyTimestamp":"\/Date(1445003454083)\/"} ,
  {"id":3,"description":"All things Strle","name":"Strle","site":"http://Strle.com","CreateId":"CRGA","CreateTimestamp":"\/Date(1445003454083)\/","ModifyId":"*Load*","ModifyTimestamp":"\/Date(1445003454083)\/"}]
```

My objects are coming back with name, site, description. I expected that would be enough to render the page -- but it doesn't. I notice `{ "_id" : { "id" : 99}` in all of the example objects. Is that what's working against me? If it is, what is that doing?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was the `{ "_id" : { "id" : 99}` working against me. I changed the _id to id in the app.js file in the config module:

```
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
      id: 'id'
  });
```

Then in the models on the html page, on the list.html detail.html sections I replaced `._id.$oid` with `.id`. After that it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have solved the problem yourself, but I want to share my experiences with you nonetheless. It's not strictly answering your original question but maybe it will save you some headaches in the future.

**Serverside**

It's quite handy to wrap your data that should be consumed by Restangular with a tiny viewmodel like this:

```
public class RestangularWrapper<T>
{
    public T Items { get; set; }

    public dynamic Meta { get; set; }
}
```

When I started out with Restangular I only used anonymous objects as a result which became quite a mess over time. Wrapping the results like this makes it much clearer what you're actually doing / returning.

**Clientside**

To consume this result with Restangular you need to add a ResponseInterceptor in your app.run() function:

```
angular.module("myApp").run(["Restangular", function run(Restangular) {
        Restangular.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
            var result;
            result = data.Items || {};
            result.meta = data.Meta;
            return result;
        });
    }]);
```

I have all my Restangular calls inside a service which gets injected wherever I need to. So using the setup described above, looks something like this:

The service with Restangular

```
(function ()
{
    "use strict";

    angular.module("myApp").factory("myService", myService);
    myService.$inject = ["Restangular", "$log"];

    function myService(Restangular, $log)
    {
        return {
            getSomeData: getSomeData
        };

        function getSomeData(currentPage, pageSize, searchTerm)
        {
            return Restangular.all("some/paged/result").getList({
                    page: currentPage,
                    pageSize: pageSize,
                    search: searchTerm || ""
                }
            );
        }
    }
})();
```

Using the service in a controller

```
(function ()
{
    "use strict";

    angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", myController);
    myController.$inject = ["myService"];

    function myController(myService)
    {
        var self = this;
        self.resultCount = 0;
        self.pageCount = 0;
        self.items = null;
        self.pageSize = 8;
        self.currentPage = 1;
        self.isLoading = false;

        /*...more code for handling the paging, etc would go here...*/

        function loadDataFromServer(searchText)
        {
            self.isLoading = true;
            myService.getSomeData(self.currentPage, self.pageSize, searchText)
                .then(function (responseData)
                {
                    self.resultCount = responseData.meta.TotalRecordCount;
                    self.pageCount = responseData.meta.PageCount;
                    self.items = responseData;
                    self.isLoading = false;
                });
        }
    }
})();
```

I hope this is a bit helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add that tip Xceno.